# HttpClient PostAsync returns error 404 Not found in .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, httpclient, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to call the webapi using httpclient. but it's not recognizing method and always throw 404 error.

My api Action method is like this.

```
[Route("AddEmployee")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostTEmployee([FromBody]Employee emp)
    { // doing something here}
```

And the calling method is like below

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {i

                    String BaseUrl = "http://ip:port/";
                    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);
                    AuthenticationHeaderValue parsedAuthToken = null;
                    bool authParsed = AuthenticationHeaderValue.TryParse(authToken, out parsedAuthToken);
                    if (authParsed)
                    {
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = parsedAuthToken;
                    }
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    string serialisedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp);
                    HttpContent content = new StringContent(serialisedData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                    response = await httpClient.PostAsync("AddEmployee", content);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                    }

                }
```

I am stuck with this issue from 2 days. Not sure what is the mistake? please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Totally a wild guess but is your endpoint `/api/AddEmployee` not `/AddEmployee`?

try changing

```
response = await httpClient.PostAsync("AddEmployee", content);
```

To

```
response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/AddEmployee", content);
```

Comment: The end point is fine. it's a custom one. it's working fine when call the api directly from postman so end point is not a problem i guess.

Comment: How about if you get rid of the code for setting the `BaseAddress` and putting the absolute path in the Post method?